# Send Invitation using event like iCal (Calendar)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar, icalendar

In my app, I have to develop functionality for calendar invitation using even.

**So just I want to know that Is there any way to send invitation and send email to it for invitation like iCal(Calendar)?**

Please give me suggestions or any idea for above functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u will have to use server side i guess

Comment: @amar any linke or any idea without server side?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can opt for a server side solution, but if your app does not use a server side the you can add local notification to remind the user he needs to send an invitation. and code it to open mail composer directly.

Comment: yes in my app,there is not used server side bcoz i m using core data but client requires calendar invitation like native iCal so if possible using server side option please give me link or any idea how can we do that one calendar invitation to send gmail,mac mail etc